# Can RS flip flops be made of only 2 MOSFETs?

Tags: transistors, mosfet

I currently have a flip flop circuit based on 2 bipolar transistors (the classic circuit) that controls a PMOS (high side 3.3V switch), and the only solutions I have found to the component values make an NMOS necessary in between the flip flop and the PMOS to be able to drive the gate high to shut it off below its Vgthmin.

It feels like there is a more elegant solution, and I have had no luck so far finding or synthesizing a 2-MOSFETs RS flip flop to try to connect its output directly to the PMOS gate. Hence my question, is this actually feasible?

More info: 3.3V for IOs + flip flop supply + PMOS source side, SET has 4.7kOhm output impedance whereas RESET is much lower

Comment: Please show circuit, and required inputs and outputs (states, voltage levels, current requirements)

Comment: There is no circuit, the question is general. The specific info was only contextual but I can just as well remove it

Comment: (and also I have to scrap everything that's there when swapping to MOSFETs, so there is basically nothing to show. Requirements at the bottom of the question)

Comment: I mean, there are three flip-flops, using both N, both P, or N and P transistors (and resistors, diodes, and some strong assumptions about what counts logic input and output levels/strengths). You ask one question (can it be made) and the answer is a trivial "yes". Then you ask whether it's "feasible" for an unknown application (which isn't exactly general).

Comment: So the answer is yes, a RS flip flop can be made with only 2 MOSFETs and passives? Darn it, I really am blind then. Thanks. I'll keep looking then, but just like there exists a typical NPN-based RS flip flop example circuit without any need for requirements, I'm interested in such an example for MOSFETs (any, I'll adapt). Or hints, I'm still annoyed at the fact I didn't come up with it myself yet :) If I give requirements and a solution is given, it would take the fun out of it right?

Comment: I mean, it's well known in the literature, not very different from the BJT case, and the others are derived by symmetry (so it's really just the one, with the P/N being a bit of a special case of that). If you mean as a puzzle/challenge to "invent" it from basic elements, I guess; if you know the basic logic operation you need, then just cross reference the voltage thresholds on transistors and synthesize the circuit.

Comment: I'm convinced I've only come across BJT flip flop circuits and >2 MOS circuits, but perhaps I would have if I had the 2nd volume from Horowitz & Hill. Although I do have a terrible memory. My problem thus far was that the logical operations needed required 2x2 MOS but I'll keep digging

Comment: Did changing the diodes to silicon (rather than Schottky) make the simulation work properly? (I'd expect it would. I may be wrong :-) ).

Comment: Sorry, I didn't keep the sim file. I think that I had silicon diodes before but I'm not sure

Comment: @MisterMystère  Why would my olution NOT latch correctly in practice, with either ideal diods, or silicon diodes? (With Schottky diodes it pobably wont.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean "using only two MOSFETs and some passives", then yes:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4gHts.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Using N-channel devices:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxZIU9.png)</sup>

Inputs NR and NS are now active low, meaning for example that to "set" Q, you must pull NS low.

Comment: Your and my circuits seem to have an undefined initial state. Once either side "wins" the cct is stable. I wonder of there is a possibility of a 'both partially on' state? If so it would be very unstable.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon it's undefined in the sense there is a DC operating point where both transistors are equally biased, but it wouldn't last long, because there's positive feedback which will be "triggered" by even the slightest mismatch anywhere, or tiniest amount of noise.

Comment: Yes the undefined state is the startup state of the flip flop when both RS are inactive, but I don't mind that. Thanks Simon, I confirm they both work. Challenging in my application without added circuitry because I got a cap on the other side of the Set diode that prevents the flip flop from switching in time, but you've answered the question. I feel both dumb and smarter at the same time

Comment: I am struggling to understand how this implements an SR latch (not sure I understand why we're calling this a flip flop?). Would it be possible to help me understand what happens when we go from SR = 00 to 10, for example, and, say, in the PMOS implementation? I think my issue is in not following how to interpret a diode in the context of a logic circuit. By definition of an SR latch I should go from Q arbitrary on the output (I can see how the PMOS circuit is stable at *either* Q = 1 or Q = 0) to Q = 1. If I go to S = 1 and Q = 0 initially does this mean the 1 passes through the diode and...

Comment: ...strongly forces Q = 1, eventually setting us into that stable state? How should I think about the diode "propagating" this value? Conversely, what if Q = 1 initially? I suppose the diode is then roughly an open and so the S input going high is immaterial? Thanks very much for any help you can give me! This came up for me in the context of reading Weste and Harris and their comment that Kilby made the first IC by building a two transistor flip-flop -- I was not aware one could do this with only two transistors, and I suppose I should interpret flip-flop here as meaning latch?

Answer (score 2):

> Can RS flip flops be made of only 2 MOSFETs?

I may have missed something, but this seems to work
S & R are high level triggered.
Add capacitors and timing R if needed.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbuXiM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Brain says this looks so obvious that I MUST have missed something. Yes?

Comment: Well, don't I feel stupid here. I had a diodes circuit, I had a 4 MOS circuit, and didn't think about combining them. Shame on me - thanks Russel. I'll double check in LTspice and tell you here but sure seems to work eyeballing it!

Comment: @MisterMystère Both WSimon's and my circuits seem to have an undefined initial state. Once either side "wins" the cct is stable. I wonder of there is a possibility of a 'both partially on' state? If so it would be very unstable.

Comment: Looks like the diodes are backwards in your circuit for NMOSes so although you were the first to answer (I appreciate it, thanks) I'll have to accept Simon's answer - but I confirm that otherwise the sim works. If only for the undefined start state, but that is a common theme for simple flip flop circuits. In my specific application the startup state does not matter.

Comment: @MisterMystère I think not (and may be wrong :-) ). We just drive somewhat differently. He uses negative levels for set and rset. I use positive. He pulls down a resistive positive so can drive the related drain directly plus a connected other gate as the transistor is off. || I use positive inputs. If I drove a low drain high I would be fighting the on FET - which is why I have the gat resistors - I drive the gates but not the drains. || SO I need two more resistors to allow NMOS and positive levels. || He uses two less resistors and needs negative levels. || Whichever works for you is best.

Comment: @MisterMystère I'm entirely happy for you to accept his answer rather than mine regardless of which you use. rep is just something that happens to happen along the way :-).

Comment: I thought so too before simulating it, but unless I'm mistaken, the flip flop does not retain its state this way: https://ibb.co/hDfwMP7

Comment: @MisterMystère Interesting. Try changing diodes to silicon. [1N5817](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/26/db/14/60/52/47/47/5b/CD00001625.pdf/files/CD00001625.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00001625.pdf)  page 2 - has leakage of 0.5 mA at 25 C. That's equivalent to under 10k pull down on gate here. [1N4148](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/ds12019.pdf) is about 25 nA at 20V. || Results would be of interest.